# Counting tetrahedrons inside a dodecahedron

Tags: group-theory, geometry

The regular dodecahedron has $20$ vertices, and $12$ faces which are (congruent) regular pentagons; three pentagons meet at a vertex.

Fixing a vertex $v$ of dodecahedron, we count the other vertices, whose minimum distance from $v$ is $3$. One can see the Schlegel diagram of the dodecahedron [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlegel_diagram).

There are exactly $6$ vertices at distance $3$ from $v$: call them $x,x',y,y',z,z'$.

With figure below (Schlegel diagram), we can see that we can partition these six vertices into two sets, such that vertices in each set are at distance $3$ from each other.

Thus, from the vertex $v$, we produced $2$ tetrahedrons, with one vertex common.

But, I was unable to see **from this construction**, why do we get only $10$  regular tetrahedrons inside regular dodecahedron? Can anybody explain it?

(Note: I know some other way - going via cubes, and then tetrahedrons; but, here I am trying to understand it from the Schlegel diagram, for better understanding of the diagram and explanation.)

**why this question came?** There are $20$ vertices in Dodecahedron, and tetrahedron has $4$ vertices, so if we want to get $10$ tetrahedrons, I was unable to see how the repetition of vertices is coming in tetrahedrons while distributing vertices of dodecahedron.
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I did not get statement "$2$ from each of $10$ vertices"; which $10$ vertices? Are you partitioning $20$ vertices of Dodeca in some way to get $10$? can you elaborate more?

Comment: Ah OK, sorry, typo! I meant "2 from each of 20 vertices, each of which is counted once for each of its 4 vertices, making a total of $(20 \times 2)/4 = 10$ tetrahedra". In any case Robert Z has now answered the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For any vertex $v$, we find $2$ regular tetrahedrons and therefore we get a total number of $20\cdot 2=40$ tetrahedrons. But in this way,  each tetrahedron is counted $4$ times (recall that a tetrahedron has 4 vertices). Hence there are just $40/4=10$ different regular tetrahedrons.

Answer (score 2):

The only regular tetrahedra in the dodecahedron occur for choices of vertices in the Schlegel diagram for which the [distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_(graph_theory)) between any two tetrahedral vertices is $3$.  It is not difficult (using a vertex coloring argument) to show, for example, if $v$ is chosen as a tetrahedral vertex (WLOG), then the only other candidate vertices are $(x, x', y, y', z, z')$.  But since the tetrahedral graph is $3$-regular, these six choices must correspond to at most two valid tetrahedra, since these must be partitioned into two triplets.

So if $v$ admits exactly two tetrahedra, and there are $20$ dodecahedral vertices, then there are $20 \times 2 / 4 = 10$ distinct tetrahedra:  $20$ by permuting dodecahedral vertices, $2$ for two distinct tetrahedra per vertex, then divided by $4$ because each tetrahedron has four vertices.